# dto entity for form or create special dto form entity for form

Tags: java, spring, api, dto

Lets imagine that I have user entity and some registration form. Should I return userDto or I should return some RegistrationForm entity and map it to domain model.

Comment: Have you tried to the approach in my answer? Could you please check and let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you don't need a `RegistrationForm` entity and `User` entity would be enough to keep user data. On the other hand, you can create two separate dto e.g. `SignupRequest` for sending form data to the corresponding service and `SignupResponse` for sending response after registering the user.

Here is an example usage:

```
@Data
public class SignupRequest {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

```
@Data
public class SignupResponse {

    String message;
    Long userId;
    String username;
    String accessToken;
    String refreshToken;
}
```